# Sigma Ring flash

Tags: flash, sigma

I am using sigma ring flash with Nikon d7100 for 3 years and had no problem. Recently, my images are coming full black eventhough flash is firing. I usually use camera in aperture mode, however, even with manual mode same problem. I tried changing flash modes also but none seems to solve the problem.
[image]

Comment: I am not sure how to add photo here. As i told, i use aperture mode and camera selects other settings on nikon. ISO i used 200, camera selection of shutter is usually 1/60, ring flash selected TTL mode. Image is fully black .

Comment: Full black? Do you hear the mirror & shutter of your camera? Do you see something in the viewfinder before taking the picture?

Comment: I hear shutter sound, flash also fires and i can see everything in viewfinder. Only problem is when i look in pictures it is full black as if no light. When i take picture without external flash everything is normal.